# PHP Retrieve minimum values in a 2D associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below array:

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array
        (
                [id] => 1
                [price1] => 16
                [price2] => 10
                [price3] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [price1] => 19
            [price2] => 2
            [price3] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3

            [price1] => 14
            [price2] => 32
            [price3] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to get the lower price from each row independent from the other rows. for example for `id=1` the lower price is `3` and for `id=2` the lower is `2` and so on. Any idea how to automate this.

Comment: You might want to use `min()` in a `foreach` loop. http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

[Demo](http://codepad.org/MKQP1fXf)

```
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $lowestKey = '';
    foreach($item as $key => $value)
    {
        if(strpos($key, 'price') === 0)
        {
            if($lowestKey == '')
            {
                $lowestKey = $key;
            }
            else
            {
                if($value < $item[$lowestKey])
                {
                    $lowestKey = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo 'lowest for id ' . $item['id'] . ': ' . $item[$lowestKey];
}
```

The benefits of this method are:

- The price keys don't have to be consecutive, or even numerical. Any key that begins with `price` is treated as a price.
- There can be unlimited prices, it's not restricted to three.
- Any other data stored in the array won't affect it or break anything. So for example if in future you added a `description` key, it won't affect the code or require any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $row)
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    unset($row['id']);
    $newarray[$id] = min($row);
}
```

There you go. `$newarray` now contains the `id => {lowest value}` of each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = array_reduce($array, function(&$result, $item) {

    $key = $item['id'];
    unset($item['id']);
    $result[$key] = min($item);
    return $result;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
$prices = array(0 => array ( 'id' => 1,
                         'price1' => 16,
                         'price2' => 10,
                         'price3' => 3
                        ),

            1 => array ( 'id' => 2,
                         'price1' => 19,
                         'price2' => 2,
                         'price3' => 6
                ),

            2 => array ( 'id' => 3,
                         'price1' => 14,
                         'price2' => 32,
                         'price3' => 1
                )

    );



foreach($prices as $price) {
    $tmp_arr = array(0=> $price['price1'], 1=> $price['price2'], 2=> $price['price3']);
    sort($tmp_arr);
    $arr_low_price = array('id'=> $price['id'], 'low_price' => $tmp_arr[0]);
    print_r($arr_low_price);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try may help:

```
$price  = array();
foreach( $array as $key=>$each ){
    $low    = $each['price1'];
    if( $each['price2'] < $low ){
        $low    = $each['price2'];
    }
    if( $each['price3'] < $low ){
        $low    = $each['price3'];
    }
    $price[$key]    = $low;
}

print_r( $price );
```